# Jquery Masonry with PHP content pulled from database

Tags: jquery-masonry

So I'm working on a PHP site that pulls the data from the database and formats it into an html post. This php page then repeats that process for all the posts from the database. The index.php page then pulls all those posts into itself for display.

I've got masonry working only part way. It recognizes the container on index.php, but not the individual items being pulled in.

I know this is vague. I don't know php myself, trying to learn it. The php was built by someone else who isn't working on the project anymore. I'm simply trying to redesign the front end. I have a flat html version of the site with masonry working perfectly.

Comment: Can you show us some code? I think it's more a mysql and php problem?

Comment: Do those individual items have a specific class? It is impossible to tell anything without looking at any code.